# Embedded C++: Initialization of an array member of a struct within a class, size omitted

Tags: c++

Hello there and thanks in advance for any help on the following matter.

Edit:  *I forgot to add that this is on an embedded system with no access to STL features.*  My apologies for leaving this very important piece of information out.  This is my first time coding in C++ extensively so I forgot to mention the obvious.  I came back to add this fact and this question had already received some replies.  Thank you all for such a quick response!

I am trying to initialize an array member of a struct that is in turn a public member of a C++ class.  The array size is omitted in the struct.  Here is an example:

```
// ClassA.h

Class A  
{
   public:

   struct StructA
   {
      StructB structs[];
   }; 

   struct StructB
   {
      // stuff
   };

   ClassA();
   //etc
};

// ClassB.h

ClassB: public ClassA
{

  public:

  StructA structA;

  ClassB()
  // etc
};

// ClassB.cpp

// What do I do here?
```

I tried:

`StructA ClassB::structA.structs[] = { first, second, third }`

without any luck.  I'm relatively new to C++ so this one has stumped me.
I can add a size to the array member in StructA but I would rather not if
there is a legal way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: You say "static initialization" in your title but I see no statics/globals here at all. Was that your intention?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I believe you are correct.  I shouldn't have added static to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's hard to create something that has a variable size in C or C++, without resorting to dynamic allocation, which you should try to avoid when using embedded systems.

I would suggest that you would create a plain array of things, and place a pointer to this inside your class. You can place the array in global scope, and the pointer does not have to know it's size.

In addition, by simply placing something in a class doesn't make it global. You must either make it a `static` member (meaning that there will be exactly one variable, regardless of how many objects of that particular class there is), or initialize it in the constructor.

For example:

```
class A
{
public:
  struct B
  {
    char const * str;
  };

  // Constructor
  A(A::B * beePointer)
    : mB(beePointer)
  {
  }

  // Data members
  B * mB;
};


// Global array
A::B my_Bees[] = {"first", "second", "third"};

A my_a(my_Bees);
```

Of course, in this solution, you can't add more elements to the end of the array, as it is allocated once and for all.

Comment: Thanks, Lindydancer, this looks like an interesting solution.  I'll try this out.

Comment: I tried something similar to what you suggested here and it worked fine for my purposes.  I changed the omitted size array in StructA to a pointer to a list. Then, I created a static array in file scope of StructB structs similar to what you had shown above.  Then, I simply assign the pointer to the list of StructBs (in StructA) to the static array I've allocated.  I do this in the constructor and it works great.  It all seems obvious in retrospect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Arrays without a size aren't valid C++; they're a feature in C99, where they require some `malloc` magic to function. If you try to compile code using this feature with `g++ -pedantic`, you'll see that it emits:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic test.cc
test.cc:5: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'foo'
```

I suggest you use `std::vector` instead, which has the same function as unsized arrays in C99 but is much safer:

```
std::vector<StructB> structs;
```

then add elements with `push_back`.

Comment: Thank you larsmans.  I left out a huge factor in that I'm coding on an embedded system and have no access to the STL.  I've been working with this mindset for so long, I forgot to include the obvious!  Therefore, I can't use vectors or STL features.  I think the answer is then that I must add a size to the array in the original struct (structA).

Comment: @TheSpiceMustFlow: yes, you'd have to give it a size. Or you might want to port `std::vector` to your platform. Check out STLport, http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/

Answer (score 2):

Since you code in c++ anyway, why not use:

`std::vector<structA> mStruct;` ...
`mStruct.push_back(first);` ...

std::vectors are quiet comfortable in comparison to c-array and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have unsized arrays in C++. Since you don't have access to `vector`:

- If you know the maximum number of items you'll never need, just size your array to that value.
- If you don't know the maximum number of items you'll never need, you'll have to dynamically manage your memory in some way. You can try `new`/`delete` by default but you may need to create your own memory pool if the defaults aren't performant enough.
- If the very last line of your post indicates that you only ever need one copy of the array in the whole program, AND that you know what values to initialize to at compile time you can use a static class member. Your sample code had multiple problems so I had a hard time guessing what you wanted.

A sample of how the static would look though:

```
// ClassA.h

class ClassA
{
   public:

   struct StructB
   {
      // stuff
   };

   struct StructA
   {
      static StructB structs[];
   };


   ClassA();
   //etc
};

// ClassB.h

class ClassB: public ClassA
{

  public:

  StructA structA;

  ClassB() { }
  // etc
};

// ClassB.cpp

ClassA::StructB first, second, third;

// What do I do here?
ClassA::StructB ClassA::StructA::structs[] = { first, second, third };

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark.  I tried your method but the compiler complains that "ClassA::StructA::structs[] is not a static member of ClassA::StructB."